# Why is Hausdorff Measure used on surfaces integrals?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, surface-integrals, hausdorff-measure

I have a mild curiosity as to why are we using the Hausdorff measure to define surface integrals (for example the co area formula) and not use instead the Lebesgue measure, or at least on my class and notes i have seen the definition like this:

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a regular surface of dimension d, and g a function defined on that surface to the real numbers, g Hausdorff measurable, then we define the integral of g over M as:

$\int_{M}{g d\sigma}:=\int_{M}{g d\mathscr{H}^{d}}$

I am sorry if i don't really get my point across i am a bit confused on this.

I would appreciate any clarification!

Comment: Do you mean $n$ dimensional Lebesgue measure? If so, then imagine your function is the constant function $1$, and then your integral could end up asking to find the area of a line, which is $0$.

Comment: Yeah i mean n dimensional, but I still can't understand why we use Hausdorff measure, because (I am not sure about this) isn't it the same thing on the Boreals sets?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to with "Hausdorff measure", but as for why Lebesgue measure won't work it's because the dimensions are off. N dimensional Lebesgue measure is defined from n dimensional "rectangles", but if you have, say, an n-1 dimensional surface you can cover it with infinitely thin rectangles, so you'll get a measure equal to zero.

Comment: I'm referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure, but one question, if i have the "correct" dimension for the Lebesgue measure, so let's say d-dimensional, would that work?

Comment: That's really not well defined. Let's take a 2d surface in 3d. What are your basic 2d rectangles that lie in your surface and whose areas kick-start your definition of 2d Lebesgue mesure? What you can do is define the "surface element", often written $dS$, often defined as the norm of the cross product of the partials wrt a parametrization of your surface, but when you do that you've really gone beyond what anyone would call Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I'll add that I haven't worked much with using Hausdorff measure to do integrals, but only for defining "dimension". For actual integrals over manifolds, things that have parametrizations, I'm used to stuff like this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral. The integral you're asking about seems very general, and I guess you want to be able to integrate over weird sets, like fractals. I can't help with that, but I do know that you can't just use Lebesgue measure. I'm not sure if I've convinced you that the dimension matching problem is as fatal as it actually is.